# click no such command found

Tags: python, command-line-interface

I am trying click (Command line interface package for Python), while running the following code I get error `Error: No such command "abcd"`

```
@click.group()
@click.option('--source', required=True)
@click.pass_context
def cli(ctx, source):
    ctx.obj = "pass it"

@cli.command()
@click.argument('abcd')
@click.pass_context
def hello(ctx, abcd):
    click.echo("Hello, World")


if __name__ == '__main__':
    cli()
```

I am running it as follows

```
python playclick.py --source this abcd
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"abcd" is being treated as a separate command because of the space (this is a characteristic of your shell, not of click specifically).

If you want the value of `source` to be "this abcd", use quotes:

```
python playclick.py --source "this abcd"
```

---

To actually provide the `abcd` argument, you need to call the `hello` command – the argument is for that command:

```
python playclick.py --source this hello 123456
```

The `hello` command will have an argument of `123456`.

Breaking down the entire line:

`--source this` provides the `source` argument to the main `cli` command.
`hello` is the command to run (try `python playclick.py --source this`  and you'll get an error because there is no command), and `123456` is the argument named `abcd` to that command.

Answer (score 1):

For those who are only using `@click.argument` but still getting the same `no such command found` error, what finally helped me solve this issue with (`7.1.2`) was just to remove uppercase letters in the command name.